# Can't use node in Garuda linux

Tags: node.js, linux, libstdc++

After installing node in Garuda linux , when I write node in terminal this shows :

> node: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by node)

Everything is checked and up to date...

Comment: GLIBCXX_3.4.29 is an object in libstdc++ - 11.x, from gcc version 11.x .......... Please update to g++ / libstdc++ version 11.x or use a different "node" package.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thanks, I was having this issue in WSL(Manjaro), I installed gcc and now everything is working fine.